# dojo 1.5 select set not working

Tags: select, dojo, set

HI, I want to use select button in my application. So I am trying with a simple select example. I have a tried alot with different options. I could not succeed in setting the value of select button. Please gothrough the following code and correct me.

> ```
>       <script type="text/javascript"> dojo.require("dojo.parser");
> dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");
>     dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
>     dijit.byId('selectv').set('CA',California);
>     });
> </script>
> <select name="selectv" dojoType="dijit.form.Select">
>         <option value="TN">
>             Tennessee
>         </option>
>         <option value="VA">
>             Virginia
>         </option>
>         <option value="WA">
>             Washington
>         </option>
>         <option value="FL">
>             Florida
>         </option>
>         <option value="CA">
>             California
>         </option>
>     </select>
> ```

I would like to set the value of select box using set method. I have seen different options with attr pre-1.5, but it didnt work. Please let me know the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your `set` call is rather off.  The line you wrote would attempt to set an attribute called `CA` (which doesn't exist) to whatever the value of a variable named `California` is (which probably doesn't exist either).

What you really want to do is probably:

```
dijit.byId('selectv').set('value', 'CA');
```

Which would set the value attribute of your Select widget to the string `CA`, which would result in the California option being selected (as its value is `CA`).

And yes, `get` and `set` are preferred over `attr` in 1.5 (`attr` will still work, but it's deprecated, and you'll see warnings if you have `isDebug: true` in `djConfig`.)